# Как присвоить значение переменной в синглтоне android проекта?

Tags: android, kotlin

Я переезжаю с java на kotlin в android проекте. Если с активностями все просто и понятно, то с синглтоном не все так просто как хотелось бы. Я не могу понять как присвоить значение переменной контекста. Получается что в java есть сеттер которым можно прилепить значение переменной а в котлине в синглтон как-то не получается так сделать. Сначала я сделал `class` но потом прочитал что нужно `object` в итоге у меня получается такой синглтон:

```
object Singleton {
      lateinit var context : Context

    }
```

но сразу же становится все желтым со словами:

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to `Singleton` which has field `context` pointing to `Context`); this is a memory leak
```

это я так понимаю предупреждение о том что возможны утечки памяти. И это не есть хорошо, в итоге я в тупике, так как у меня будет много переменных которым я буду присваивать значения из активности, и контекст мне нужен для доступа к настройками приложения. Как можно решить эту проблему с реализацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Крайне не рекомендуется хранить в singlton'ах или в случае с java в static полях что-либо, содержащее ссылку на Context. Сюда попадает и сам контекст, и активити, view  и т.п. Пока хоть что-то ссылается на контекст - сборщик мусора его не будет убивать, отсюда и могут родится утечки памяти.

в 99% случаев когда вы создаете статическое поле - вам на самом деле не нужно статическое поле.

Если прям совсем никак без сохранения контекста в этом синглтоне не обойтись - оберните его в WeekReference, и во всех метах где обращаетесь к этому полю не забываете, что WeekReference может вернуть null, если объект был собран сборщиком